# why assignments are not statements

Tags: kotlin

I have the following code:

```
class Presenter {
    private var view : View? = null

    fun attachView(view: View) = this.view = view // error: Assignment is not a statement

    fun detachView() = view = null // error: Assignment is not a statement
}
```

I know I just can write:

```
class Presenter {
    var view : View? = null
}
```

and later in code just call `presenter.view = View()` and `presenter.view = null` instead of `attachView`/`detachView`. But I think this is much less readable.

So why can't I use assignments as expression bodies in Kotlin? Why isn't assignment just a statement of type `Unit`?

Comment: It was a decision made to avoid bugs.

Comment: You can also use `get` and `set` syntax, which is much more readable. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#getters-and-setters

Comment: I haven't found anything documenting why [assignments are *NOT* expressions in Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html#Equals) but in case any readers are not aware you can use [`run`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/run.html) to treat an assignment as an expression. e.g. `fun attachView(view: View) = run { this.view = view }` but in this case you might as well use a block function, `fun attachView(view: View) { this.view = view }`, unless you want to avoid code styles that wrap block functions into multiple lines.

Comment: @mfulton26 note that the type of the assignment expression inside `run` is `Unit`

Comment: @llya Not really. [Assignments are *NOT* expressions in Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html#Equals) but as the `run { ... }` example "does not return any useful value, its return type is `Unit`" ([Unit-returning functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#unit-returning-functions)). Assignments in Kotlin do not have return types because they are not expressions but they can be used as the last statement in a code block to infer a function return type of `Unit`.

Comment: @nhaarman Could you please provide an example where that could lead to a bug?

Comment: You don't actually need the run, in this case you should just use { } to wrap anything inside your function. The "=" syntax is for when you're actually returning a value, while in this case you're just making an assignment. Assignments don't return any value, that is why you get this error. So clarifying, it should look like this: ```fun detachView() { this.view = null }```

Answer (score 1):

Whether we like it or not, this was simply a design decision which the language creators made. See this discussion for more details:

https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/assignment-not-allow-in-while-expression/339

Comment: This answer relies heavily on the content of an external link. Should that page ever go offline, your answer would lose most of its value. So please [edit] it and add some more details of what can be found there. Consider that if the value of an answer lies *only* in the content of external sites, that answer is very likely to be removed. Thank you!