# How to define a oneline function calling a nullable variable function

Tags: kotlin

If I have something like:

`fun showProgressView() = ultraRecyclerView?.showProgressBar()`

it says that it returns `Unit?` and not `Unit` (edited)

-----EDIT-----

One way can be
`fun showProgressView() = ultraRecyclerView?.showProgressBar() ?: Unit`

but it looks not right for me.

Another way:
`fun showProgressView() { ultraRecyclerView?.showProgressBar() }`

But I cant find a way for android studio maintain that format.

Comment: You can simply add `?: Unit` at the end if you want a not null return type.

Comment: `fun showProgressView() = ultraRecyclerView?.let { it.showProgressBar() }` ?

Comment: @XOOLOOO that still returns `Unit?`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you use the short expression form of a function, the inferred result type of the expression determines the function return type.  If that is a platform type from Java, it could be nullable.  If it is a Kotlin type then it will know the correct nullability.

But since you use the safe operator `?.` you are saying for sure it could be nullable.  And if the result is `null` or `Unit` then that gives the inferred result type of `Unit?`

Which is odd, but is exactly what you are saying.  Therefore, either use a normal function body with `{ .. }` or give the function an explicit return type if possible.

```
fun showProgressView(): Unit { ultraRecyclerView?.showProgressBar() }
```

You can also erase the nullability, by creating an extension function on `Unit?`:

```
fun Unit?.void() = Unit
```

And use it whenever you want to fix the return type:

```
fun showProgressView() = ultraRecyclerView?.showProgressBar().void()
```

Comment: Is there ever a case where the distinction between `Unit` and `Unit?` is relevant though? I can't really think of anything right now, but maybe I'm overlooking something. To me it seems like the compiler should automatically infer the return type as `Unit`.

Comment: @mhlz that would be a discussion for somewhere else, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com, slack channel, or discussion forum.  Unit is not so special and the code is ambiguous, so I personally would prefer to report it as an error when used as an expression with `Unit?` as the result.  But it isn't that big of a deal to me either way, and is accurate what it is doing.

Comment: Does `fun showProgressView(): Unit = ultraRecyclerView?.showProgressBar()` actually work for anyone? I get "Type mismatch. Required: kotlin.Unit Found: kotlin.Unit?".

Answer (score 3):

IntelliJ IDEA / Android Studio do not appear to have a setting to keep the style of a block body function on a single line. Even so, you can use [`run`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/run.html) to get around this:

```
fun showProgressView() = run<Unit> { ultraRecyclerView?.showProgressBar() }
```

Normally you do not need to add explicit type arguments to `run` but in this case providing them gives you the desired method signature (return type of `Unit` and not `Unit?`).

Note: This answer is adapted from a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35602364/why-assignments-are-not-statements#comment58892306_35602364) I gave to [why assignments are not statements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35602364/3255152).